# Why can't we call StopForeground() method in the broadcast receiver class?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications, foreground-service

I have a broadcast receiver class and when I receive a particular broadcast I would like to stop the foreground notification. So I tried `context.stopForeground()` but the intellisense did not show the method. How can we call the `stopForeground()` method in the broadcast receiver class ?

```
public class Broad extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


         if(intent.getAction()==Const.ACTION_STOP)
        {

             // unable to call like this
            context.stopForeground();

        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stopForeground()` is part of the `Service` class and therefore it cannot be called from either the receiver or the `context` provided to it.

To setup a `BroadcastReceiver` in your existing `Service` as an instance variable:

```
    private final BroadcastReceiver mYReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Bla bla bla
            stopForeground(NOTIF_ID);
    };
```

You register this receiver in your `Service` only (possibly on `onStartCommand()`), using:

```
IntentFilter iFilter = new IntentFilter("my.awesome.intent.filter");
registerReceiver(mYReceiver, iFilter);
```

This will enable `mYReceiver` to be triggered whenever a broadcast with that `IntentFilter` is fired which you can do from anywhere in your app as:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent("my.awesome.intent.filter"))
```

Comment: Can't we get a reference to the service class and then call the method ?

Comment: @WeirdNerd Yeah, its a public method in the `Service` class. So, you just need a `Service` instance to call it.

Comment: How do you get a service reference object in the broadcast receiver ?

Comment: @WeirdNerd Why don't you stop it from the `Service` instance only? You can put the same receiver as above within your `Service` and simply call `stopForeground()` there.

Comment: you mean create an inner class that inherits broadcast receiver inside the service ?

Comment: @WeirdNerd Yeah, anonymous inner class. Check my edit above.

Comment: Just one more doubt if you are using an anonymous inner class then what do you specify in the intent ? Like Intent i = new Intent(MyClass.this, //); What will be the target class ?

Comment: I also figured out an another way => Intent i = new Intent(MyClass.this,mYReceiver.getclass()); will also do the job right ?

Comment: @WeirdNerd I don't think it works that way. Is it working for you?

Comment: Are you sure ? How ?

Comment: @WeirdNerd I have never seen it being used in the way you mentioned in your comment above. I always specify an `intent-filter` string like in the answer.

Comment: Yeah that won't work because we are using an anonymous inner class and cannot refer to that in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop it from broadcast receiver
//In your receiver

```
      @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       context.stopService(new Intent(context, YourService.class);
}
```

Also add stopForground (true) in onDestroy method of relative service