# Android Best-Way to communicate with a Foreground Service

Tags: android, service, foreground

I am bit new to android. I would like to know how to communicate with a foreground started service.

So, I got a Foreground service with a notification. 
This notification has a (X) button to stop the service.

The service got a Static broadcastreceiver.

```
public static class NotificationStopButtonHandler extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Toast.makeText(context,"Close Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "In Closed");

            // imposible to do context.stopForground(true) or
            // to call any other private coded by me
        }
}
```

So my question is : 
Is BroadcastReceiver is the best way ? 
If it is : How I can communicate with the service to call stopForeground in the broadcastReceiver ?

Thanks in advance for your responses.

[Same question like mien...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38726398/why-cant-we-call-stopforeground-method-in-the-broadcast-receiver-class/40310473#40310473) But I would like to know which are the other solution than broadcastReceiver. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your notification you will have a PendingIntent for the X button. I presume you have built that PendingIntent with

```
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(/* ... */);
```

What you can do instead is to create a PendingIntent for your service

```
Intent intent = /* intent for starting your service */;
intent.putExtra("STOP_FOREGROUND", true);
PendingIntent.getService(context, requestCode, intent, flags);
```

and in the intent you pass to the PendingIntent you would add an extra (STOP_FOREGROUND). When this intent is fired, your service will get called in onStartCommand(). Here you check the intent and if it contains your extra, you know you're expected to call stopForeground.

Comment: Hello @Francesc, first of all thanks for your answer. Thats effectualy one of the solution that works perfectly. I was always bit reserved to not use this because it enters in the OnStartCommand. For me, it's like everytime you do getService.. you want to start it. But looks like this is the best way to do. At the difference of broadcast receiver, PendingIntent I guess is "local" I communicates only with my app. More over, I also implemented a LocalBroadcastReceiver (that i can not attach to a notification) in order to communicate easly with my Service or self call with my service itself.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of broadcasts, you can use [PendingIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) with an Intent to the Service and tell the Service to shut down. You assign the `PendingIntent` to the close button action and/or to the `notifications` [onDelete call](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setDeleteIntent(android.app.PendingIntent)) when you build the notification.

Assuming that you're starting the Service with the notification, you can put commands in the Intent to tell the service to stop itself. `Service#onStartCommand` will be called on the service with the new Intent.  The service checks for the shutdown call and calls `stopSelf()` when done.

Basically, the reason this works is because there can only be one Service started. Every subsequent attempt to start the service will send the intent to `Service#onStartCommand`, but it will not restart the `Service`. Thus, this is a way you can send commands to the service through means outside of binding.  Plus it's *way* cleaner than using broadcasts.

Comment: Thanks @DeeV the onDelete call is so useful in my case !